# How to control baby swing?

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, speed

I am starting an intresting DIY project of baby swing. My son is 3 month old and we have swing made with ropes in our house where he sleeps. I am looking for any electronic component controlled with arduino to swing it in controlled manner. I thought of servo motor but not sure how will it work. Any suggestions please ?

swing is similer to below

[image]

Comment: your question is not related to the arduino ... you may get better results elsewhere ... try this for a proof of concept ... tie a length of string to one of the ropes about 30 cm from the ceiling ... gently pull the string repeatedly using small motion ... think about how much a hobby servo would pull the string ... doing that will give you an idea about how much force is needed to get the swing going and what is needed to keep it at a steady swing

Comment: sure! Thanks @jsotola

Comment: Have you considered a solenoid? The one we used many years ago used a solenoid and a few "D" batteries, a magnet and a reed switch.

Answer (score 0):

A simple DC motor would work. you have to pulse it in the right moment. for finding out the *right moment* and the pulse length (you don't want to push it so hard !) you need a simple accelerometer sensor to measure acceleration in specific axis.